# Using a const-reference for assignment

Tags: c++, styles, constants, parameter-passing

I am trying to follow the Google C++ style guide, specifically [the section on reference arguments](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Reference_Arguments#Reference_Arguments). It says to always pass references as const references. This seems like a great idea because I don't want this function to mess with my `FilterBank`. However, there are places in Instrument where I need to change `*filter_`, so making `filter_` const isn't a good solution. Does this mean that I should instead be passing in a pointer, `FilterBank *f`? Is it just an issue of style to do that? Whatever `f` was can be changed in this function if so desired, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

```
//This code assigns the instrument's filter to some pre-made filter, f
void Instrument::set_filter_bank(FilterBank &f) {
  filter_ = &f;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "..where I need to change `filter_`..." do you mean the pointer, or the object it *points to*?

Comment: *"I am trying to follow the Google C++ style guide"* -- Why?

Comment: I meant what it points to--thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to allow the `Instrument` class to have access to modify a `FilterBank` object via a member pointer (`filter_`).  You set this member pointer via a member function `set_filter_bank`.  You don't want this member function to modify the object, and so you want to make it a `const` reference.

But this reasoning is flawed.  The `set_filter_bank` function needs to be able to grant write access to the `filter_` pointer.  The problem is, a function cannot grant access which it does not have itself.  So, even though the function does not modify the object, it needs to have the *right* to modify the object in order to grant that right to someone else.  So, whether you make it a reference, or a pointer, it cannot be const.

So, if you insist on following the Google Style guide, then the appropriate parameter here is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like this is explained in the "Decision" section of the link you've given:

Decision:

> Within function parameter lists all references must be const:
>
> ```
> void Foo(const string &in, string *out);
> ```
>
> In fact it is a very strong convention in Google code that input
>   arguments are values or const references while output arguments are
>   pointers. Input parameters may be const pointers, but we never allow
>   non-const reference parameters except when required by convention,
>   e.g., swap().
>
> However, there are some instances where using const T* is preferable
>   to const T& for input parameters. For example:  •You want to pass in a
>   null pointer. •The function saves a pointer or reference to the input.
>   Remember that most of the time input parameters are going to be
>   specified as const T&. Using const T* instead communicates to the
>   reader that the input is somehow treated differently. So if you choose
>   const T* rather than const T&, do so for a concrete reason; otherwise
>   it will likely confuse readers by making them look for an explanation
>   that doesn't exist.

It looks to me like they are saying if you are passing an input value to a function use a const reference, but when you are defining an output value use a pointer.  This is to make it clear to the consumer what your function is expecting.  The const enforces the promise that you won't change the pointer.

Comment: One of the many issues I've always had with the Google style guide ... forcing output parameters to be raw pointers.